# Printing to terminal in a color

Tags: php, console

Basically, I wish to have 3 printers to print in error state, success state or info state which means nothing but different colors.

```
    class ColorCode{
        private static $options = [
            "dark_gray"     => "1;30",
            "light_gray"    => "0;37",
            "blue"          => "0;34",
            "green"         => "0;32",
            "cyan"          => "0;36",
            "red"           => "0;31",
            "yellow"        => "1;33"
        ];

        public static function get($key){
            if(isset(self::$options[$key])){
                return self::$options[$key];
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    }

    class ColorPrint {
        public $color = '';

        function __construct($color) {
            $this->color = ColorCode::get($color);
        }

        public function printc($msg) {
            echo "\033[". $this->color ."m".$msg."\033[0m\n";
        }

    }

    $out = [
        'error'     => new ColorPrint('red'),
        'info'      => new ColorPrint('cyan'),
        'success'   => new ColorPrint('green'),
    ];
    $out['error']->printc('Invalid Option');
```

Answer (score 4):

I like your code, but I just have a couple of small points:

- Be consistent with your spacing (around `{` and especially `.`).
- I doubt that this will work on Windows, so I would check if the script is run on Windows, if it is, just print without color (or find a way to use color in Windows), and maybe trigger a warning.
- I would rename `printc`, either to the shorter `print` (because it's easier to remember, and you don't really lose any meaning), to `print_color` (if you want to make it really really explicit that it is in color), or `print_console` (in case you also later implement something like `print_web` with CSS).
- I would not just ignore it if a color is requested that does not exist, but handle it in some way (throw an exception, trigger a warning, etc). Otherwise users might wonder why `ligth_gray` or `orange` do not result in any color changes.

Comment: isn't print reserved keyword

Comment: also how to best throw exception

Comment: also what's your view on last 4 lines

Answer (score 2):

Your code would not be very helpful in an IDE like phpstorm.

I regularly use `echo "some text"`.  Probably a lot of people do.

Other would use `print()`.

Consider a function `echolor("some text", CONSTANT_FOR_COLOR_AND_OR_ERRORS)` [literally "ECHO with coLOR" :)].  Much shorter and more readable.

Now I just need to learn to use parentheses, and the IDE would recognize the color constants.

Make the constants start with a simple 2- or 3-letter unique prefix.  This would then be a very memorable and usable system.

```php
    $out['error']->printc('Invalid Option');

    #vs.

    echolor('Invalid option', CC_WARN);
```

Comment: `echolor` is cute, but is it "more readable"?  I strongly disagree.  This is even going to confuse non-English speakers.  What constants need a 2/3 letter prefix?  I am confused by this review and its current score.

Comment: I added an example comparison.  The user can name the method whatever the Sam Hill they want to.  But the method has a declarative approach of `do('This thing', THIS_WAY)`.  No `[]->` stuff AND an IDE would recognize and even color code the constant.  I'll leave any final wise comments to you but perhaps that explains any concurrence with my approach.

Comment: I object to the notion that you should program for your IDE. Your IDE should support you, not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for your wise comments!